# Not able to find when gcc links to libc

Tags: c, gcc

I was trying to study the compilation/link process in detail using gcc.
So made a test .c file and compiled it using the verbose option of gcc.

```
gcc -v main.c
```

But in the verbose messages I cant find anywhere where it refers to libc. The only relevant (might be) thing I find is crtn.o and crtend.o

But when I do

```
readelf -d a.out
```

I can find the dependency on libc.so.6. So I am confused whether gcc doesn't output the message related to dynamically linking to libc or I am missing something.

The relevant message for the linker is as below:

> LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
>   COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
>    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. /tmp/ccYoVOxt.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o

Comment: I have edited the question , I used gcc -v main.c. And also added relevant message for the linker

Comment: @melpomene I've rolled back your edit as it made the question harder to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library operand you are looking for is `-lc`. It's in there, use Ctrl+F to find it.

See also [the ld documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/Options.html#index-g_t_002dl-_0040var_007bnamespec_007d-58).